# Android Studio Gradle freeze on :app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build, release

After adding some libraries to our Android project and changing the compileSdkVersion to 26, our application stopped building in the release-configuration. The process stops at 93% at the stage: app: transformClassesWithDexForRelease and after 15 minutes of work there is no change. At that, the processor is loaded by 75%, and the RAM is 83%.
We use Android Studio 3.0, gradle 2.3.3, Windows 10 x86 with 3GB RAM. 
Also we tried to set different values for javaMaxHeapSize. Here is our build.gradle file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 204
        versionName "2.4"
        applicationId "ua.ers.simpleVpn"
        //testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "1g"
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs-aar'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs/appodeal')
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs/appodeal_dex')
    compile project(':library-circular-mod')
    compile project(':complexPreferences')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.3'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    //Appodeal
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'
    //Appodeal
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    //for Inmobi
    compile name: 'adcolony-sdk-3.3.0', ext: 'aar'
    compile name: 'mobvista-8.11.0-alphab', ext: 'aar'
    compile name: 'mobvista-8.11.0-common', ext: 'aar'
    compile name: 'mobvista-8.11.0-interstitial', ext: 'aar'
    compile name: 'mobvista-8.11.0-interstitialvideo', ext: 'aar'
    compile name: 'mobvista-8.11.0-mvdownloads', ext: 'aar'
    compile name: 'mobvista-8.11.0-mvjscommon', ext: 'aar'
    compile name: 'mobvista-8.11.0-mvnative', ext: 'aar'
    compile name: 'mobvista-8.11.0-nativeex', ext: 'aar'
    compile name: 'mobvista-8.11.0-playercommon', ext: 'aar'
    compile name: 'mobvista-8.11.0-reward', ext: 'aar'
    compile name: 'mobvista-8.11.0-videocommon', ext: 'aar'
    compile name: 'mobvista-8.11.0-videofeeds', ext: 'aar'
    compile name: 'mobvista-8.11.0-videojs', ext: 'aar'
}
```

Please help, since we have been struggling with the problem for more than a week, and the update schedule of the application is tight. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As recommended in [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/). **Recommended Ram is 8gb**, i just wonder if you can even run Android Studio in 3gb ram system. Because i have 10gb ram in which 6gb ram is always reserved by **JDK (3gb)** and **Android Studio (3gb)**. And my system is having i7 processor which gets hang when i am working with data binding.

Your app run on low config system when it does not have much dependencies, but you will require minimum 8gb ram if project is going to big structure and more dependencies.

**Solutions:**

- Increase ram to at least 8gb.
- Try to use some useful classes instead of all package in your dependency.
- Clean project, sometimes unused packages remain in Build.
- Use proguard (will remove unused classes and resources itself) if you are building release app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We tried to clean project and we using proguard as you can see above. Increasing the size of RAM is possible only by purchasing a new PC, since the old PC has a 32-bit processor.

Comment: I want tell one more thing, that if you add some dependency for first time in project, then build will take huge time. But next time when it has cache, then it will build in seconds(or just 1 minute)

Comment: Yes, we are in the know. However, in our case, we waited more than 15 minutes and did not get a result, so most likely gradle froze.

Comment: Low config systems have this issue. You should increase Ram for sure.